# Graph cut based on visibility

Tags: c++, graph, 3d, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

According to the following figure, a surface mesh can be extracted using an Energy function = L, where L is number of intersection of a triangle.
[Graph Cut algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28x8N.png)
I would like to know how would I construct the graph and apply cut to it using C++.

According to that library

http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html

I can construct a graph like that

```
 typedef float GraphCost;
  typedef Graph<GraphCost, GraphCost, GraphCost> GraphType;
  GraphType *graph = new GraphType(nodeCount, 3*nodeCount, error)
```

;

Where vertices are the vertices of the delaunay 3d triangle, and edges are the edge of a 3D deluany triangles in a mesh.

But how would I continue and use a graph cut to cut that mesh based on visiblity

I have camera position and I can project rays towards the vertices of the mesh.

An example of how to use graph cut for octree is here

https://github.com/turiphro/martijn-msc-thesis/blob/master/code/objects/occupancy_grid.cpp